# How to efficiently organise firestore methods and connections

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm current working with Firebase firestore and Next JS. I've googled how to organise a firestore project but most of them (all actually) aren't scalable.

What I have tried to do is to have a folder containing all the Firebase-related components such as configurations and utility methods. I found the most challenging part is to write a general-purpose function to get the collection/document ref that applies all the supported methods, namely `.orderBy()`, `.limit()`, `.where()` and `.doc()`. It's also really tough to write a transformer that transforms the data returned by the database to another format.

Here's what I have implemented:

[image]

Where `getDocRef.js` is a helper function that puts all those methods mentioned above together, `getOnce.js` and `observe.js` expose methods that interact with the database and `db.js` contains the configurations.

Also, for anyone who interested, here's my naive solution for the `.getDocRef()` function:

```
import db from '../db';

/*
  Options:
  - ref: Specify the ref of a document
  - collectionName: Specify the collection name
  - queryArgs: Specify the arguments to be passed down to .where()
  - orderByArgs: Specify the arguments to be passed down to .orderBy()
  - limit: Specify the fetching limit
  - docName: Specify the document name/id
*/
export default options => {
  const { ref, collectionName, queryArgs, orderByArgs, limit, docName } = options;

  if (ref != null) return ref;

  const initRef = db.collection(collectionName);

  if (docName != null) return initRef.doc(docName);

  if (queryArgs != null) {
    if (orderByArgs != null) {
      if (limit != null)
        return initRef
          .where(...queryArgs)
          .orderBy(...orderByArgs)
          .limit(limit);
      return initRef.where(...queryArgs).orderBy(...orderByArgs);
    }
    return initRef.where(...queryArgs);
  }

  return initRef;
};
```

So, I would love to know if my current implementation of Firebase is okay. If not, what project structure should I apply? How should I improve my current structure to make it more efficiently? And last but not least is there an alternative to my naive JS solution posted above? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal approach:

- Extract all credentials to `.env` with `dotenv` package
- A directory call `/lib/db` and two files here:

  - `init.js` to initialise the `Firebase/firestore`
  - Another class with some methods for CRUD

If your project is getting big, I suggest to extract every collection's related method to a file in `/lib/db` and organise them there(somehow like state managements).

Comment: That would make sense. I’m waiting for other answers before accepting yours

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is what I do in a big medium to big project. and in a small one, if you put them all in one file, still make sense